# INTERSECT Range for Only Specified Non Ajacent Columns VBA

Tags: excel, vba, intersect

My c ode below checks what column is currently activated and if it is a specific number it does one thing, for another column it does another thing, etc.

How can I force the code to abort if the column selected is not one of the columns I have actions written for?

I am only interested in proceeding through code for example if the column number selected is 10, 12, 16, 18 or column Letter is L, P or R.  If it is anything else, I want to code to do  nothing.  At the moment If I copy and paste in ranges outside of the columns mentioned above, the msgbox messages within code when Column = 10 is activated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Dim CurrentCell As String
Dim rangeToChange As Range
Dim C As Range, V


' Set rangeToChange = Range("PipelineTable[Status]")
CurrentCell = ActiveCell.Value
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error Resume Next
'MsgBox "Target Column is " & Target.Column


    If Target.Column = 12 Then
        GoTo AddActivityDate
    End If
    If Target.Column = 16 Then
        GoTo AdvisorNextAction
    End If
   If Target.Column = 18 Then
        GoTo OfficeNextAction
    End If
    If Target.Column = 10 And (Target.Value = "THIS Month – Payment Due") Then
        Range("K" & Target.Row).Value = Range("I" & Target.Row).Value
        Range("I" & Target.Row).Clear
        MsgBox "Moved Commission Due to Month Paid"
    End If
    If Target.Column = 10 And (Target.Value = "Issued But Not Paid") Then
        Range("K" & Target.Row).Value = Range("I" & Target.Row).Value
        Range("I" & Target.Row).Clear
        MsgBox "Moved Commission Due to Month Paid"
    End If
    If Target.Column = 10 And (Target.Value = "Not Going Ahead") Then
        Range("I" & Target.Row).Value = 0
        Range("K" & Target.Row).Value = 0
        MsgBox "Moved ZERO to Initial Commisson and Month Paid"
    End If


AddActivityDate:
    'Update on 11/11/2019 -If data changes in column L Activity , insert
    'today's date into column M - Date of Activity

        Dim WorkRng As Range
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
        Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("L:L"), Target)
        xOffsetColumn = 1
        If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each rng In WorkRng
                If Not VBA.IsEmpty(rng.Value) Then
                    rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Now
                    rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
                Else
                    rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
                End If
            Next
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If

AdvisorNextAction:
    'Update on 11/11/2019 -If data changes in column L Activity , insert
    'today's date into column M - Date of Activity

        Dim WorkRng2 As Range
        Dim rng2 As Range
        Dim yOffsetColumn As Integer
        Set WorkRng2 = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("P:P"), Target)
        yOffsetColumn = 1
        If Not WorkRng2 Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each rng2 In WorkRng2
                If Not VBA.IsEmpty(rng2.Value) Then
                    rng2.Offset(0, yOffsetColumn).Value = Now
                    rng2.Offset(0, yOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
                Else
                    rng2.Offset(0, yOffsetColumn).ClearContents
                End If
            Next
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If

OfficeNextAction:
    'Update on 11/11/2019 -If data changes in column L Activity , insert
    'today's date into column M - Date of Activity

        Dim WorkRng3 As Range
        Dim rng3 As Range
        Dim zOffsetColumn As Integer
        Set WorkRng3 = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("R:R"), Target)
        zOffsetColumn = 1
        If Not WorkRng3 Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each rng3 In WorkRng3
                If Not VBA.IsEmpty(rng3.Value) Then
                    rng3.Offset(0, zOffsetColumn).Value = Now
                    rng3.Offset(0, zOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
                Else
                    rng3.Offset(0, zOffsetColumn).ClearContents
                End If
            Next
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If

     Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If you put `Exit Sub` above `AddActivityDate:` that would do it.  You should also do that for each of your `Goto` sections if that is the last thing you want to happen.  Also recommend getting rid of `On Error Resume Next`.  You are not doing yourself any favors to hide errors.  There are times when it is appropriate, this isn't.

Comment: Instead of using `goto`, consider using a function that you pass the appropriate range to

Comment: Darrell.  Thank you so much.  You have saved me so much time.